# Bluetooth headphones sound muffled - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, sound-card, headphones

I've just got a new PC, and when connecting my bluetooth headphones (Mpow 059) the sound is really muffled and distant sounding. I used these on my old PC (also windows 10, with the same mpow bluetooth adapter) and it was fine. Also my headphones via 3.5mm jack sound fine on this PC.

In the sound mixer there are two options:
Headset (MPOW-059 Hands-Free AG Audio) - this works but sounds muffled
Headphones (MPOW-059 Stereo) - this has no sound at all

My mobo is Gigabyte B450.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try updating the Bluetooth Driver?  Look in Device Manager, Bluetooth, make sure all Bluetooth devices are working and update the Bluetooth connection/wireless driver. Restart and see if that helps.

Comment: @John I updated it in device manager. However to fix it I had to download the drivers from MPOW.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by downloading the specific drivers for my bluetooth adaptor from the MPOW website.